# How to stop all social icons activating simultaneously when one of them is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Whenever one social share icon is clicked then all other social icons also get triggered.
[image: screenshot]

This is my HTML.

```html
<div class="share">
  <div class="toggle"></div>
  <ul>
    <li><a id="facebook-icon-hover"  href="#">  <i class="facebook-icon-hover fab fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
    <li><a id="instagram-icon-hover" href="#">  <i class="instagram-icon-hover  fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
    <li><a id="youtube-icon-hover"   href="#">  <i class="youtube-icon-hover  fab fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
    <li><a id="whatsapp-icon-hover"  href="#">  <i class="whatsapp-icon-hover  fab fa-whatsapp"></i></a></li>
    <li><a id="pinterest-icon-hover" href="#">  <i class="pinterest-icon-hover  fab fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
    <li><a id="snapchat-icon-hover " href="#">  <i class="snapchat-icon-hover  fab fa-snapchat"></i></a></li>
    <li><a id="tumblr-icon-hover"    href="#">  <i class="tumblr-icon-hover  fab fa-tumblr"></i></a></li>
    <li><a id="twitter-icon-hover"   href="#">  <i class="twitter-icon-hover  fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is my JS.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle').click(function(){
      $('.toggle').toggleClass('active')
      $('ul').toggleClass('active')
    })
  })    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are toggling `active` class on **all** elements that have `toggle` class and all `<ul>` on every toggle click. You should toggle `active` classes only on clicked element and closest `<ul>`. Use event input argument inside provided callback function and toggle class only on that element (and its siblijng - `<ul>`):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle').click( function(event) { // event as input
    const el = $(event.currentTarget); // extract clicked element from input Event
    el.toggleClass('active'); 
    el.next().toggleClass('active'); // find first sibling, which is <ul> in your case and toggle class 'active' on it
  })
})
```